# Nginx: how do I rewrite a URL subdirectory to a query parameter?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I am trying to rewrite a URL in a WordPress website running Nginx so that the last subdirectory is transformed into GET-parameter:

http://mydomain/property/aid/1234/ to http://mydomain/property/?aid=1234/

I tried with `add_rewrite_rule` in WordPress, but it didn't work as it didn't create a new `$_GET` entry.

Then I tried the following Nginx rule:

```
rewrite ^(/property/.*)/aid/(.*)$ /$1/?aid=$2 break;
```

which seems to have no effect at all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the document root is `/www/yourproject/public`. Then the configuration for PHP-FPM may look like the following:

```
rewrite "^/property/aid/([0-9]+)$" /property/?aid=$1 break;

location /property/ {
  root            /www/yourproject/public;
  fastcgi_pass    unix:/tmp/php-fpm-yourproject.sock;
  fastcgi_index   index.php;
  include         fastcgi_params;
}
```

In this configuration, the requests are processed by `/www/yourproject/public/property/index.php`.

**Sample `index.php`**

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
```

*Sample output for `/property/aid/1234`*

```
array(1) {
  ["aid"]=>
  string(4) "1234"
}
```

You can replace `fastcgi_pass` and `fastcgi_index` directives with a [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass), for instance.